# Import Image Overlay KML to Google Earth Engine Won't Display

Tags: google-earth-engine, kml, google-earth, google-fusion-tables

I would like to import an image overlay in KML format made in Google Earth App to Google Earth Engine, and display it. Below attached the link of KML file:

[KML file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-bayssrCdFaretIBWCpSp7pLIzzFWSbG/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

I have imported also the KML to Fusion Table, and then get the id as follows: 1KpWHxXMbjF0mRUHbrxacqXK30B_en7kF7dVUP8KK

The code script that I made in the Google Earth Engine to display the image overlay KML file is as follows:

```
// Import KML
var basins = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1KpWHxXMbjF0mRUHbrxacqXK30B_en7kF7dVUP8KK');
Map.addLayer(basins);
```

When I run the code, the KML didn't appear. I guess my code script was incorrect, what should I do to correct the code?

Comment: The image in the KML has a relative URL in the href `<href>peta_cekungan_sedimen_indonesia.jpg</href>`  You'll need the full URL to show the image elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your KML has not been converted to fusion table properly. There are no rows/features. Fusion tables are getting shut down after December 3rd anyways so it might be a better idea to go a different route. One way is to conver the KML to SHP and then upload that directly to GEE.

Edit: Sorry it seems I completely missed the image part. But yea, since you want to import an image from KML to GEE then you need to convert that to a geotif and upload that to GEE as fusion table supports KML with distinct shapes/geometries. [source](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171181?hl=en)

Comment: There are no rows/features in the KML, it's an image.

Comment: Fusion tables are supposed to import vector data with rows and features that has a well defined geometry [source](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171181?hl=en). If you want to import images from KML to GEE then one way is to export them as a geotif and import that file as asset in GEE